# Javascript: why my indexof would return the row where the value is found

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

I have written this code with the purpose of cycling through a list of names. When the code finds the waitingName in the list it should replace the row that the name appears with a row of info. When I attempt to run this code it pastes the row of information at the top of the screen, not after row 17 where the list of names begins.

```
 var waitingName = waitingSheet.getRange(6,13).getValue();
 var edittedInfo = waitingSheet.getRange(6,3,1,12).getValues();
 var waitingListNames = waitingSheet.getRange(17, 11, 105,1).getValues().flat();
 var index = waitingListNames.indexOf(waitingName);
 if (index > -1) {
   waitingSheet.getRange(index + 1,1,1,12).setValues(edittedInfo);
 }
```

Comment: If this uses an excel or google sheets library you're going to want to add the appropriate tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution:

- `index` takes values `>=0`, therefore `index+1` takes values `>=1`. This
  is why your code starts pasting from the **first** row.

If you want to paste the information after **17th** row (including 17th row) then modify this:

```
waitingSheet.getRange(index + 1,1,1,12).setValues(edittedInfo);
```

to this:

```
waitingSheet.getRange(index + 17,1,edittedInfo.length,edittedInfo[0].length).setValues(edittedInfo);
```

since `index` can take values `>=0`, `index + 17` takes values `>=17` which is the desired starting row point.

Also, it is recommended to use `.length` instead, in case you want to change the size of `edittedInfo` down the road.

---

### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)
- [length()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)